# Cannot render js unicode character `\u1F310`

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-escapes, unicode-literals

For example omega symbol rendered properly `'\u03A9'`, but globe symbol     `'\u1F310'` http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f310/index.htm - not. Was tried on console and node environments

Comment: Read this https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'\u1F310'
```

JavaScript `\u` escapes only take four digits, so this string literal is two code units, U+1F31 (Greek Small Letter With Dasia) and U+0030 (Digit Zero): `ἱ0`.

JavaScript strings are made of 16-bit-wide code units, so the highest single code unit in JavaScript is `\uFFFF` and characters from U+10000 upwards, lying outside the Basic Multilingual Plane, cannot be referenced directly. To get them, you have to use a pair of [UTF-16 surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). For U+1F310 that works out as `'\uD83C\uDF10'`.

In ECMAScript 2015, there's a new string escaping form that takes the character number and works out the rest for you: `'\u{1F310}'`. This is [available](http://node.green/#Unicode-code-point-escapes) in recent versions of Node, but it will be a while before support is widespread enough in browsers.

Printing the character to console is a separate challenge. As @MarcoS says you will need your terminal to be set to use a font that has a glyph for it. You will also need to be using a console that understands non-ASCII and in particular non-Basic-Multilingual-Plane characters. (If you're on the Windows command prompt, the only way to win that game is not to play.)

Comment: So fonts from @MarcoS answer is no matter?

Comment: You would certainly need to set a font with a glyph for that character as well, if you want to view it in-place. (If you just want to output it to copy-paste elsewhere you can do that without a font.)

Answer (score 1):

Only some fonts support globe symbol `'\u1F310'`...
Some of them are:

- LastResort
- Quivira
- Segoe UI Emoji
- Segoe UI Symbol
- Symbola
- Unifont Upper CSUR

See [fontsupport](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f310/fontsupport.htm)